# Extra credit activity in class: how to handle grading

Tags: grading

I teach an undergraduate engineering elective where I used to have a project for about 20% of grade. Rest used to be the usual exams, quizzes etc.

Now the class size has grown to about 100 and it is no longer viable for me to have a mandatory project assignment due to time limitations etc

However some students do express an interest in doing a project and I would want it as an activity for additional/ bonus credit.

Any thoughts how people manage such extra credit activities in the grading rubric? Should it be way an extra 20% on top of the usual and then we normalise back to 100%? What's the right incentive/ reward structure.

PS. I could also use this to reward some difficult questions etc that come up during class.

Answer (score 3):

I have a structure in one of my classes where the “core” material I want everyone to do comes out to a B grade if completed on time, with the extra material available if they want to boost to an A or make up for late assignments.

Most students understand that it’s me telling them “here’s the subset of the material you should do if you just want a B”, but there’s always a small number of students each year who get fixated on the idea that “they have to do extra credit to get above a B”.